# How to redirect in Private Route in React?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an issue with my PrivateRoute component. It supposed to redirect user to specific page in case of specific circumstances, but it's not. After login, my conditional is working, but I'm not redirected to the correct page. I just see `/#`, which is default redirect from b2c I'm using.

**Component:**

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const { authStatus } = props;
  ...
  if (authStatus === AuthStatus.SomeRole) {
    // conditional is working
    return <Route exact path="/specificUrl" render={() => <Redirect to="/specificUrl" />} />;
  }
  ...
};
```

**My App:**

```
const App: React.FC = () => (
  <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
    <Switch>
      ...
      <PrivateRoute path="/specificUrl" component={SpecificComponent} />
      ...
    </Switch>
  </Suspense>
);
```

What I'm doing wrong? If I change code to this:

```
if (authenticationStatus === AuthenticationStatus.SignedInNotInPilot) {
  return <Redirect to="/specificUrl" />;
  // return <Route exact path="/specificUrl" render={() => <Redirect to="/specificUrl" />} />;
}
```

I'm redirected to `/specificUrl` but `SpecificComponent` is not loading.

But if I change code to this `SpecificComponent` is loading but I have to redirect manually:

```
if (authenticationStatus === AuthenticationStatus.SignedInNotInPilot) {
  return <Route exact path="/specificUrl" render={() => <SpecificComponent />} />;
  // return <Redirect to="/specificUrl" />;
  // return <Route exact path="/specificUrl" render={() => <Redirect to="/specificUrl" />} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first logic works, but to redirect you can try bringing { withRouter } out of react-router-dom, then wrap your component with it while exporting like an higher order component. This will give you access to the history prop, you can then use history to redirect using history.push('/specificUrl')

```js
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'

const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = (props: PrivateRouteProps) => {
  const { authStatus, history } = props;
  ...
  if (authStatus === AuthStatus.SomeRole) {
    // conditional is working
    return <Route exact path="/specificUrl" render={() => history.push('/specificUrl') />} />;
    // or just history.push('/specificUrl') should work as well
  }
  ...
};

export default withRouter(PrivateRoute)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```